# Altium. Can't apply a rule of plane connect to Polygon

Tags: altium, pcb-layers, design-rules, polygon

Problem with Altium Designer!
I'm trying to use Plane Connect to Polygon with four conductors, but in existing PCB it dosen't work. (in new projects it working)
What could be wrong?﻿

My actions: 1) Set Plane Connect rule. 2) Repour all polygons. (also i'm tried to repour selected polygon)

The rule:
[image: The rule]

The polygon (GND):
[image: The polygon]

Comment: I think you should try the Polygon Connect Style rule instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another section of the rules.

The picture below shows which one:
[image]

In the Altium Plane and Polygon differ slightly from each other.

**Plane** - Less flexible, but quickly processed by the program and does not take large computing power. Also on this layer you can not rout.

**Polygon** - More flexible for editing, but repour requires more computing power.